# How to fix "error: could not find native static library `c`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?" or how do I compile rust binaries for openwrt?

Tags: rust, embedded-linux, rust-cargo, openwrt

I'm wanting to compile binaries for openwrt 19.07.7 on mips with limited space.

```
 OpenWrt 19.07.7, r11306-c4a6851c72
 -----------------------------------------------------
 root@OpenWrt:~# df /
 Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
 overlayfs:/overlay        3392      1276      2116  38% /
 root@OpenWrt:~# ls -s
   662 crosshello     3 helloworld
 root@OpenWrt:~# ldd --version
 musl libc (mips-sf)
 Version 1.1.24
```

Above you can see the size of crosshello (cross compiled using rust) and helloworld (cross compiled using gcc).  There is limited space on the target as you can see.

I followed https://github.com/japaric/rust-cross and it works.  However I had to reduce the size of the binary to get it to fit.  Following https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust I got the binary (the "Cross compiling with cargo" hello world with clap from the first link) to fit.  I haven't compiled my own program yet.  I got stuck a the "Optimize libstd with build-std" section.

I'm getting the above error:

```
$ cargo +nightly build -Z build-std=std,panic_abort --target=mips-unknown-linux-musl --release
   Compiling libc v0.2.106
...
error: could not find native static library `c`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?

error: could not compile `libc` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

How do I fix that?  I don't want to static link against the system libc, I want it dynamically linked like other binaries on that platform.  But not sure how to do that.  If I use the standard libstd the binaries are dynamically linked just fine.

Alternatively I could try nostd but my code would need significant modification and I'm not sure that would fix this problem anyway.  Alternatively I could just go ahead compile my actual project with libstd and it might fit.  However my project is doing data logging, so the binary is competing for space with data I want to store, so I want to minimize space as much as possible.

I've also seen reference to cargo-bloat so I'll probably check that out to find what all the space is being used for in the binary.

I'm open to different strategies to achieve what I want if anyone has ideas?

On my dev system:

```
$ cat .cargo/config 
[target.mips-unknown-linux-musl]
ar = "/home/alex/projects/openwrt-sdk-19.07.7-ath79-generic_gcc-7.5.0_musl.Linux-x86_64/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_24kc_gcc-7.5.0_musl/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-ar"
linker = "/home/alex/projects/openwrt-sdk-19.07.7-ath79-generic_gcc-7.5.0_musl.Linux-x86_64/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_24kc_gcc-7.5.0_musl/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-gcc"
$ cat Cargo.toml 
#cargo-features = ["strip"]

[package]
name = "crosshello"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
clap = "3.0.0-beta.5"

[profile.release]
#strip = true
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
codegen-units = 1
panic = "abort"
```

(The binaries are stripped, currently I'm stripping them manually.)

Comment: Hitting the same error, also for an OpenWrt build for that target. Did you ever figure it out? By the way, for me the error isn't there if I remove the `-Z build-std=std,panic_abort` build option - I think it's just related to rebuilding `std`. In that regard I suspect it doesn't impact the ultimate dynamic or static linking of the binary.

Comment: No, so far I haven't come back to it yet, but I'm still interested in how to do it.